# Cannot Invoke 'responseObject' with an argument list of type (('WeatherResponse?, NSError?) -> Void

Tags: ios, alamofire

Using Xcode 7.1
Used the AlamofireObjectMapper framework from [Github](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). I am not able to use the responseObject handler.

Below is the code:

```
let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/f583be1121dbc5e9b0381b3017718a70c31054f7/sample_json"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseObject{(response :WeatherResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       print(response?.location)
        }
```

EVen if I remove the **'-> Void'** from the code there is no difference. WeatherResponse is a custom class with the following code:

```
class WeatherResponse: Mappable {
var location: String?
var threeDayForecast: [Forecast]?

required init?(_ map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    location <- map["location"]
    threeDayForecast <- map["three_day_forecast"]
}
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: same problem? did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for `responseObject` is

```
public func responseObject<T: Mappable>(completionHandler: (T?, ErrorType?) -> Void) -> Self
```

note that the error parameter is an `ErrorType?`, not `NSError?`. The proper way to call the closure would be:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseObject{(response: WeatherResponse?, error: ErrorType?) -> Void in
   print(response?.location)
}
```

Be sure to import `Alamofire`, `AlamofireObjectMapper` and `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: i implemented the second line of your code...still the same error...do i need to setup the responseObject function also...

Comment: Did you import Alamofire, AlamofireObjectMapper and ObjectMapper?

Comment: I have added my sample project on GitHub. Can you please have a look and help me. https://github.com/sahil25/AlamofireObjectMapper-Example

Comment: For whatever reason you're redefining the `Mappable` protocol in `WeatherResponse.swift` (?). Deleting that protocol redefinition and applying the suggestions in my answer solve the compilation issue.

Answer (score 0):

importing AlamofireObjectMapper & ObjectMapper in Model solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Currently with version 2.1 you could use:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
    .responseObject({ (response: Response< WeatherResponse, NSError>) -> Void in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print(response.result.value)
        }
    })
```

Good luck!